# Wedriver.IO is not including screenshots of execution done on a Remote Selenium Grid Hub in my Allure Reports

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webdriver-io

**wdio.conf.ci.js has the following appended.**

```
afterTest: function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {

if (passed){
   browser.takeScreenshot();
}
```

},
**Screenshot of the Report, in bottom right corner I am expecting Screenshot Attachment. Please advise.**
[image]

Comment: reporters: [
    "spec",
    "dot",
    [
      "junit",
      {
        outputDir: "./reports",
        outputFileFormat: function (options) {
          // optional
          return `results-${options.cid}.${options.capabilities.browserName}.xml`;
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      "allure",
      {
        outputDir: "reports/allure-results",
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: false,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
      },
    ],
  ],

Comment: Do i need async and await here ??? Maybe that could be the issue...

Answer (score 0):

in my `wdio.conf.ts` I have

```
afterStep: async function (step, scenario, result, context) {
    if (!result.passed) {
        await browser.takeScreenshot();
    }
}
```

> note: I wanted screenshot on fail only, your aim might be the opposite

So I recommend putting your screen shot logic in the after**Step** hook and not in a after**Test** hook.

And for allure-reporter config (if you use this service, but I expect you do) use:

```
"allure",
                {
                    outputDir: "allure-results",
                    useCucumberStepReporter: true,
                    disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
                    disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
                },
```